# убрать класс после закрытия fancybox 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

в 3 было так:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    afterClose: function () {
        //window.location.reload();
        $(".modal-content").removeClass("active");
    },
});
```

А как в 4?

Comment: Насколько осведомлен, выше 3 версии там уже нет jquery (плагин на js), и юзать как-то так: `Fancybox.bind('.fancybox', {
  on: { close: function (f, s) { //code } } });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox]', {
on: {
  destroy: function (fancybox, event) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.modal-content').forEach(function (content) {
      content.classList.remove('active');
    });
  },
},
```

});